# Hyperplane conversion between vector form and cartesian form

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

**Vector form to Cartesian form**

In $\mathbb{R^2}$ a $\mathbb{R^1}$ object can be expressed as

$$\text{vector form: }s\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}c\\d\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\text{cartesian form: }\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\x-c&y-d\end{vmatrix}=0$$

In $\mathbb{R^3}$ a $\mathbb{R^2}$ object can be expressed as

$$\text{vector form: }s\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}d\\e\\f\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}g\\h\\i\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\text{cartesian form: } \begin{vmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\x-g&y-h&z-i\end{vmatrix}=0$$

$\vdots$

> In $\mathbb{R^n}$ a $\mathbb{R^{n-1}}$ object can be expressed as
>
> $$\text{vector form: }s_1\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\ \vdots\\a_n\end{pmatrix}+s_2\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\ \vdots\\b_n\end{pmatrix}+\dots+s_{n-1}\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\ \vdots\\c_n\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}d_1\\d_2\\ \vdots\\d_n\end{pmatrix}$$
> $$\text{cartesian form: } \begin{vmatrix}a_1&a_2&\dots&a_n\\b_1&b_2&\dots&b_n\\\vdots&&&\vdots\\c_1&c_2&\dots&c_{n}\\x_1-d_1&x_2-d_2&\dots&x_n-d_n\end{vmatrix}=0$$

I always use this fomular to do the conversion, but is it true for all $n\in[2,\infty)\cap\mathbb{N}$.
What I tried is using induction, for Base case, It's not hard to show it hold when n=2, but i don't know how to write the inductive step, or is this easier to do with direct prove?

Any help or hint or suggestion would be appreciated.

---

**Cartesian form to Vector form**

If given cartesian form in $\mathbb{R^2}$:

$$ax+by+c=0$$

when $c\neq0$, $X,Y$ are intersections of the line and aixs:

$$X=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{c}{a}\\0\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } Y=\begin{pmatrix}0\\-\frac{c}{b}\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore the line can be expressed as:

$$\text{vector form: }s(X-Y)+X$$

Since $X=Y$ when $c=0$, the method above no longer works.

But $N_1=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{a}\\\frac{1}{b}\end{pmatrix}, N_2=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{a}\\-\frac{1}{b}\end{pmatrix}$ are normal to the normal of the line.

Choose any 1 as direction vector have:

$$\text{vector form: }sN_1$$

If given cartesian form in $\mathbb{R^3}$:

$$ax+by+cz+d=0$$

when $d\neq0$, $X,Y,Z$ are intersections of the plane and aixs:

$$X=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{d}{a}\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, Y=\begin{pmatrix}0\\-\frac{d}{b}\\0\end{pmatrix},Z=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\-\frac{d}{c}\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore the plane can be expressed as:

$$\text{vector form: }s(X-Y)+t(X-Z)+X$$

Since $X=Y=Z$ when $d=0$, the method above no longer works.

But $N_1=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{2}{a}\\\frac{1}{b}\\\frac{1}{c}\end{pmatrix}, N_2=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{a}\\-\frac{2}{b}\\\frac{1}{c}\end{pmatrix}, N_3=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{a}\\\frac{1}{b}\\-\frac{2}{c}\end{pmatrix}$ are normal to the normal of the plane.

Choose any 2 as direction vectors have:

$$\text{vector form: }sN_1+tN_2$$

$\vdots$

> More generally, If given cartesian form in $\mathbb{R^n}$:
>
> $$a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n+b=0$$
>
> Have intersections on $x_1$ that $X_1=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{b}{a_1}\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}$
>
> And $N_1=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{n-1}{a_1}\\\frac{1}{a_2}\\\vdots\\\frac{1}{a_n}\end{pmatrix}, N_2=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{a_1}\\-\frac{n-1}{a_2}\\\frac{1}{a_3}\\\vdots\\\frac{1}{a_n}\end{pmatrix},\dots, N_n=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{a_1}\\\frac{1}{a_2}\\\vdots\\\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}\\-\frac{n-1}{a_n}\end{pmatrix}$ are normal to the normal.
>
> Choose any $n-1$ as direction vectors have: $$\text{vector form: }s_1N_1+\dots+s_{n-1}N_{n-1}+X_1$$

Comment: Yes it's true, and a direct proof is probably easier. Use properties of determinants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the vector form and the cartesian form are equivalent only if the $n-1$ vectors $(a_1\;\ldots\;a_n)^T \;\ldots\;(c_1\;\ldots\;c_n)^T$ are linearly independent. Otherwise, the vector form would produce something of degree less than $n-1,$ while the cartesian form would produce the complete $\mathbb{R}^n.$ So we assume the linear independence of $(a_1\;\ldots\;a_n)^T \;\ldots\;(c_1\;\ldots\;c_n)^T$ in the following.

If the cartesian form is given, we know that the $n$ vectors $(a_1\;\ldots\;a_n)^T \;\ldots\;(c_1\;\ldots\;c_n)^T,\;(x_1-d_1\;\ldots\;x_n-d_n)^T$ are linearly dependent, which means that there are $n$ real numbers $t_1,\ldots, t_n$, at least one of them $\neq 0,$ such that
$$
t_1 \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{pmatrix}
+t_2 \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{pmatrix}
+\ldots
+t_{n-1} \begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ \vdots \\ c_n\end{pmatrix}
+t_{n} \begin{pmatrix} x_1-d_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n-d_n\end{pmatrix}
=0
$$
Assume $t_n=0.$ Then one of the numbers $t_1,\ldots, t_{n-1}$ must be $\neq 0,$ because we assumed the $t_i\neq 0$ for at least one $i\in \{1,\ldots,n\}.$ This would mean that we had the following:
$$
t_1 \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{pmatrix}
+t_2 \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{pmatrix}
+\ldots
+t_{n-1} \begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ \vdots \\ c_n\end{pmatrix}
=0
$$
But this is a contradiction to the linear independence of $(a_1\;\ldots\;a_n)^T \;\ldots\;(c_1\;\ldots\;c_n)^T.$ Therefore, $t_n\neq 0.$

We can now set $t_i = -t_n s_i$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots, n-1\}$, divide the equation by $-t_n$  and we get
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{pmatrix}
=
s_1 \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{pmatrix}
+s_2 \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{pmatrix}
+\ldots
+s_{n-1} \begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ \vdots \\ c_n\end{pmatrix}
+\begin{pmatrix} d_1 \\ \vdots \\ d_n\end{pmatrix}
$$
which shows that the given element of the hyperplane can also be expressed in terms of the vector form.

If the vector form is given, we have
$$
s_1 \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{pmatrix}
+s_2 \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{pmatrix}
+\ldots
+s_{n-1} \begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ \vdots \\ c_n\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} x_1-d_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n-d_n\end{pmatrix}
$$
which shows that the rows of the determinant are linearly dependent, which in turn shows that the value of the determinant is $0.$